# What is difference between installing angular js with help of npm vs including angular js library file in HTML page just like jquery?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, installation

Hey guys since I am learning angular js I am confused about angular js installation.

1) In some tutorials people have used angular js library just like we import jquery in HTML file.for e.g.

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"

2) and on the other hand npm is used to install angular which creates scaffolding of angular application.

So what is difference between these two methods? 
Which one is best method?

Comment: Which one is best is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs.
Installing angularjs with npm gives you the possibility to minify and concat all your javascript files in only one for exemple.
It allows you for example if you use babel to transpile your javascript es6 code into classic javascript file.
Another thing is that in some IDE (advanced code editors) like webstorm, you have some helpfull funcyions with for exemple automplete on the node modules or on the functions.
With webpack you can use the import statement to separate all your javascript files and combine them before.
In fact, if you have to create a big project with a lot of different files, you want better performances, you want to minify and concat all your files into a single file, use npm with gulp/webpack.
If you want to create a simple project for yourself and you don't want to take a lot of time to learn/configure all of that, use simple CDN.
hopes it helps you.